# How to add links on a tumblr.com page?

Tags: tumblr, links, tumblr-themes

How can I add some links on a tumblr page? For example, on http://makeclocks.tumblr.com/ I'd like to add some links at red box area:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this would have ever been on topic on Stack Overflow @mickburkejnr — @ohho, In the future: If you want something migrated, you need to `flag` it for moderator attention.

Comment: @slhck thanks for the `flag` tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each theme is different, but here's how I would of updated it on my tumblr. Knowing more about your theme's HTML would give a better answer.

Go to `http://www.tumblr.com/customize/<yourBlogName>` and click `Edit HTML`.

Within that page look for `About` within an `<h4>` tag. Mine looks like this before:

```
<h4>{lang:About}</h4>
<div id="description">{Description}</div>
```

And After I added a `Links` section (you can name it whatever you want)

```
<h4>{lang:About}</h4>
<div id="description">{Description}</div>

<h4>Links</h4>
<div id="description">link text here</div>
```

I used div id="description" because I wanted the css properties of the description div without having to edit my css.

Here's a screenshot of the before preview:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the after I put that code in preview:

[image]